# Formula Return Displaying wrong information

Tags: formula

I have a formula field `Actualization Factor (Padding)` which should return number. `PaddingNew__c` is a percentage field . 
My formula is `(1-PaddingNew__c/100)`.

Whenever i change the `PaddingNew__c` field the corresponding result should appear in the (Actualization Factor (Padding)) field.

By default this results in a wrong result.

For example: If i enter 10 as `PaddingNew__c` % its resulting Actualization Factor (Padding) as 0.999 when i change to 12 its still showing Actualization Factor (Padding) as 0.999..

Actually my requirement is to show as if padding percentage if entered as 5% Actualization Factor (Padding) should appear as 0.950

Comment: Can you Explain your Requirement clearly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. If you want to show 0.95 when the padding is 5, this is the right formula:

```
(100-PaddingNew__c)/100
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried this it worked as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As **PaddingNew__c** is a percent field so it will always hold the value from 1-100. It this assumption holds true then just change the formula to
 **(100-PaddingNew__c/100)**. It will work and gives you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the formula to (1-PaddingNew__c) it worked

Comment: If answer your own question please try and make it useful so that someone else could read it and understand it easily, e.g. post a bit more of how the formula will look in Salesforce. See [answer] for guidelines

Comment: I love when people don't even try to read the answers provided to help them.